# Sharepoint 2010 BLOB Configuration Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@RbsId"

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, sql, sharepoint-2010

HI,

I want to enable BLOB on my sharepoint 2010 portal. Portal has two servers: 1. SQL Server 2008 R2 64bit 2. Front-End Server (Windows 2008 64Bit)

I tried steps on this [url](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/andriyadi/archive/2010/07/27/configure-sharepoint-2010-to-store-files-blob-to-the-file-system.aspx) but when I execute $rbss.Enable() command, I get this error:

```
 Exception calling "Enable" with "0" argument(s): 
 "Must declare the scalar variable "@RbsId"." 
 At line:1 char:13
 $rbss.Enable ()
 CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],
 MethodInvocationException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Is there a solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the article [Install and configure Remote BLOB Storage (RBS) with the FILESTREAM provider(SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I checked. I tried theese steps too but I get same error.

Comment: Did $rbss.Installed() returned True as stated in the site you are referring..

Comment: Yes $rbss.Installed() returned True.

Comment: Did you check rbs_install_Log.txt and look for error in psconfig file specific to RBS

Comment: I found this error in rbs_install_log.txt: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ProcessComponents,Description=Updating component registration,)
Info 2769. The installer has encountered an unexpected error. The error code is 2769. Custom Action CreateFilesNoUI did not close 21 MSIHANDLEs.

Comment: If you are not in hurry.. I will do some research and get back to you on this..

Answer (score 0):

This was a permissions problem for me.  I ran it as a local admin with farm admin access, and it worked.

-gamemaster000

Comment: I tried with local administrator then I get this error :The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by **improper SQL Server collation**:

- [Can not Enable RBS because of SQL server collation for Sharepoint 2010](http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/04/19/can-not-enable-rbs-because-of-sql-server-collation-for-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Supportability regarding SQL collation for SharePoint Databases and TempDB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2008668)